# What is nim's equivalent of Python's `sys.executable`?

Tags: nim-lang

Following is the content of `foo.py`

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

When I execute this, I can get the full path of the the Python interpreter that called this script.

```sh
$ /mingw64/bin/python3.9.exe foo.py
/mingw64/bin/python3.9.exe
```

How to do this in nim (`nimscript`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mentions [NimScript](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/nims.html), which has other uses in the Nim ecosystem, but can also be used to write executable scripts instead of using, e.g., Bash or Python. You can use the [`selfExe`](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/nimscript.html#selfExe) proc to get the path to the Nim executable which is running a NimScript script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S nim --hints:off
mode = ScriptMode.Silent

echo selfExe()
```

After saving the above as `test.nims` and using `chmod +x` to make the file executable, the script can be invoked to show the path to the current Nim executable:

```
$ ./test.nims
/home/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.4.8/bin/nim
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do that in Nim (not NimScript), you can take compiler executable path using https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getCurrentCompilerExe

```
import os

echo getCurrentCompilerExe()
```

Answer (score 2):

Nim is compiled, so I assume you want to get the path of the application's own binary? If so, you can do that with:

```
import std/os

echo getAppFilename()
```